# Why cant i print unique lines from a file using bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following straightforward file:

```
ANE 
ANE
AHL 
AHL
ANI 
ANI
ANJ 
ANJ
ANK 
ANK
ANL 
ANL
ANM 
ANM
ANN 
ANN
ANO 
ANO
ANP 
ANP
ANQ 
ANQ
ANR 
ANR
AMY 
AMY
AMZ 
AMZ
```

I would like to be able to get this file:

```
ANE
AHL
ANI
ANJ
ANK
ANL
ANM
ANN
ANO
ANP 
ANQ 
ANR 
AMY 
AMZ
```

I have tried several iterations of awk:
awk '{!seen[$0]++};END{for(i in seen) if(seen[i]==1)print i}' file.txt

and several iterations of sort/uniq like:
sort file.txt | uniq -u

and somehow I STILL keep getting all the duplicates in the print out..please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There is one trailing space in every second row. Is that intentional?

Comment: please update the question with the expectedr results

Comment: @Robert, I've tried just uniq ...still getting duplicates. example `uniq file.txt` ...some of the output: 
AHL 
AHL
ANI 
ANI

Comment: do all lines have just a single string? if some lines have multiple strings then please update the question to show some of these lines

Comment: removed trailing spaces after each 3-letter word in the "results im looking for file", sorry was not intentional

Comment: no, no multiple strings, every line is just a 3-letter "word" like ANP and AMZ etc

Comment: Once you've got rid of the extra spaces, an easy way to do what you want is `sort -u file.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

If the data is already ordered such that duplicate strings reside on successive lines (as in the example), and assuming all lines contain no white space:

```
$ uniq file2.txt
ANE
AHL
ANI
ANJ
ANK
ANL
ANM
ANN
ANO
ANP
ANQ
ANR
AMY
AMZ
```

Assuming the duplicates may not be on successive lines, assuming all lines contain no white space:

```
$ sort -u file2.txt
AHL
AMY
AMZ
ANE
ANI
ANJ
ANK
ANL
ANM
ANN
ANO
ANP
ANQ
ANR
```

Now, if the duplicates are not located on successive lines and/or white space may exist in various lines, we'll look at some ideas to address OP's current `awk` code ...

The provided sample includes trailing spaces on some lines so your `awk` code ...

```
awk '{!seen[$0]++};END{for(i in seen) if(seen[i]==1)print i}'
```

... which references then entire line (`$0`) is going to treat `ABC` and `ABC`  differently.

Assuming each line only has a single string then the current code should replace `$0` with `$1` to strip off unwanted spaces, eg:

```
awk '{!seen[$1]++};END{for(i in seen) if(seen[i]==1)print i}'
```

But this still isn't sufficient because it's looking for only those strings that show up just once (`seen[i] == 1`); to print a unique list of strings consider:

```
awk '{!seen[$1]++};END{for(i in seen) print i}'
```

But if we just need a unique set of array indices then the 'not' (`!`) and increment (`++`) are superfluous, so we could further reduce this to:

```
awk '{seen[$1]};END{for(i in seen) print i}'
```

Now, since the order of the output doesn't appear to be a requirement we could keep the 'not' (`!`) and increment (`++`) and eliminate the `END{}` block; instead we'll print a string the first time we see it and then ignore it for the rest of the script:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' file2.txt
```

This generates:

```
ANE
AHL
ANI
ANJ
ANK
ANL
ANM
ANN
ANO
ANP
ANQ
ANR
AMY
AMZ
```

Comment: OMG! I cant believe I overlooked the unintentional spaces after some of those 3-letters! thank you so much for pointing that out, youre right, this was issue. thank you thank you for the thorough answer!!